# New landlord in need of guidance about tenant cleaning up property and also installing a fence for privacy In Ontario Canada

Tags: canada, ontario

New landlord in need of guidance please.
I am a new landlord who owns a duplex and is wanting to get the tenants to clean up all junk off the property outside first of all then I would like to build a fence to give them and myself privacy is it allowed in Ontario Canada?

Comment: What do you mean by “junk”? Who owns it? If it’s the tenant they have a right to keep their “junk” on the property they rent. If it’s yours, why is it the tenant’s issue?

Comment: I think you're confusing tenants with employees. That's why they give you money each month, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming based on context you're living in one half of the duplex and the tenants rent the other half.

The main issue is you seem to be confused between tenants and employees. These people pay you money to live in the property you were given. Employees are people you pay to do work for you.

You are responsible for removing the junk from your property. If it belongs to the tenants, then it would be reasonable for them to move it from a communal area, especially if it is damaging the property. However, if it is yours or if it is trash that was already there, it's your problem. Move it, hire someone, or learn to live with it.

As for the fence- again, you can't conscript your tenants to do it. You are, of course, welcome to modify your own property (within reason though a simple privacy fence should not be an issue) but you need to do the work yourself or pay for it.